# Dynamically Bind data to InnerHTML in react.js

Tags: reactjs, state, innerhtml

I have a requirement where I want to add state to innerHTML. So when the state changes the data inside innerHTML also should change.
This is my code

```
let div1=document.createElement("div")
div1.innerHTML=count
document.getElementById("mainDiv").appendChild(div1)
```

Here count is my state. It is adding initial count to div but when state of count is changed the value inside div is not changed. How to make it work according to my requirement

**EDIT**

```
import {useEffect, useState } from "react"
import EducationForm from "./EducationForm"

const ResumeForm=()=>{
const [educationDetails,setEducationDetails]=useState([])
const [show,setShow]=useState(false)
const [index,setIndex]=useState(-1)
useEffect(()=>{
    var educationDiv=document.createElement("div")
    educationDiv.setAttribute("id","education"+1)
    document.getElementById("resume").appendChild(educationDiv)
},[])

const submitEdu=(data)=>{
    let eduTemp=educationDetails
    eduTemp.push(data)
    setEducationDetails(eduTemp)
    setShow(false)
    
        let div1=document.createElement("div")
        let div2=document.createElement("div")
        let div3=document.createElement("div")
        let editBut=document.createElement("button")

        editBut.innerHTML="EDIT"
        let index=educationDetails.length
        editBut.addEventListener("click",()=>{editEducation(index-1)})
        div1.innerHTML=educationDetails[index-1].school
        div2.innerHTML=educationDetails[index-1].qualification
        div3.innerHTML=educationDetails[index-1].specialization
        document.getElementById("education1").appendChild(div1)
        document.getElementById("education1").appendChild(div2)
        document.getElementById("education1").appendChild(div3)
        document.getElementById("education1").appendChild(editBut)


}
const editEdu=(details)=>{
    let detailsTemp=educationDetails
    alert(detailsTemp)
   let detailsTemp1= educationDetails.map(obj=>{
        if(detailsTemp.indexOf(obj)==index){
            alert("inside")
            return details
        }
        else{
            return obj
        }
    })
    alert(JSON.stringify(detailsTemp1))
    setEducationDetails(detailsTemp1)
    setShow(false)
}
const addEducation=()=>{
    setShow(true);
    setIndex(-1)
}

const editEducation=(index)=>{
   setIndex(index)
   setShow(true)
}

return(
    <>
    <div id="resumeForm">
        <button onClick={addEducation}>Add Education</button>
    
       <EducationForm show={show} time={1} onClose={()=>{setShow(false)}} details={educationDetails} index={index} submitEdu={submitEdu} editEdu={editEdu} />
    </div>
    <div className="resume" id="resume">

    </div>
    </>
)


}
export default ResumeForm
```

Comment: Could you share some more of your code, so that there is a better idea of where this part of the code is being used.

Comment: @parkourkarthik made the edit can you go though it once

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the `index` is the state in actual source that you refer as `count`. You might have to add another `useEffect` which depends on `index` change like below.

```
useEffect(() => {
    let div1 = document.createElement("div");
    let div2 = document.createElement("div");
    let div3 = document.createElement("div");
    let editBut = document.createElement("button");

    editBut.innerHTML = "EDIT";
    let index = educationDetails.length;
    editBut.addEventListener("click", () => {
        editEducation(index - 1);
    });
    div1.innerHTML = educationDetails[index - 1].school;
    div2.innerHTML = educationDetails[index - 1].qualification;
    div3.innerHTML = educationDetails[index - 1].specialization;
    document.getElementById("education1").appendChild(div1);
    document.getElementById("education1").appendChild(div2);
    document.getElementById("education1").appendChild(div3);
    document.getElementById("education1").appendChild(editBut);
}, [index]);
```

Comment: Actually educationDetails is the state that I am trying to change. This code will add new div elements everytime index state changes but I want to update the div instead of adding new divs